Using symfony normalizer and doctrine to store value objects in a database column
Suppose I have this doctrine entity:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyEntityRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table('my_entity')]
class MyEntity
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id] #[ORM\Column(length: 36)] public string $id,
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')] public array $something,
    ) {}
}

Doctrine's json-column type will use json_serialize to save the $something property to a database column. Which is cool.
But suppose my class looks like this:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyEntityRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table('my_entity')]
class MyEntity
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id] #[ORM\Column(length: 36)] public string $id,
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')] public Something $something,
    ) {}
}

So the type of the $something property is now a class: Something.
I have created an implementation of NormalizerInterface and DenormalizerInterface so that the Symfony Normalizer normalizes and denormalizes instances of my Something class.
Now wonder if there is a way to let doctrine use the Symfony normalizer to convert the Something object to an array and back.
I first thought I could extend \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type to create my own doctrine-type, similar to the existing JsonType, but using the symfony normalizer instead of json_encode and json_decode. The problem here is that the function Type::convertToPHPValue() doesn't know the class to denormalize to. (And if possible, I don't want to create a dedicated type for all of my normalizable types.)
Is there anybody out there who has managed to do circumvent this problem?

I don't know if I understood your question correctly.
You want to have these typed objects (e.g. Something) in your entities, right? And you would like to deserialize these typed objects from an array (presumably some request from an API)? And then convert these object from entities back to an array when creating a response?
